# App secrets file content not being included in project output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that contains a number of projects. In the startup project, my `App.config` references another file in the `appSettings` element. But when I open the compiled `StartUpProject.exe.config` file after it is built, it does not contain the data from `AppSettings.config`.

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="AppSecrets.config">
    <add key="config variable" value="this key works"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**AppSecrets.config**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="secret config variable" value="this key does not work"/>
</appSettings>
```

The `AppSecrets.config` file is stored in the same directory as `App.config` in the project, but it is ignored from source control.

```
Solution
|_ StartUpProject
|  |_ SourceFiles.cs
|  |_ App.config
|  |_ AppSecrets.config
|_ SubProject1
|  |_SourceFiles.cs
|_ SubProject2
|  |_SourceFiles.cs
|_ SubProject3
   |_SourceFiles.cs
```

I was expecting to see something like the below in the built `StartupProject.exe.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encofing="utf-8">
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="config variable" value="this key works"/>
    <add key="secret config variable" value="this key does not work"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Are my expectations wrong? Does the `AppSecrets.config` file need to be included in the project output for this to work?

Comment: try `configSource=` instead of `file=`

Comment: Just gave that a try, same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for that is, in `file=path` path is relative to your executable file, not to your *App.config* file. So it needs to end up in same folder as *EXE* file. You need to copy it to output directory on build, just like you did.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by including `AppSecrets.config` in the project output. Not sure if this is the correct way but it worked.

I set the file 'build action' to `Content` and 'copy to output directory' to `Copy if Newer`.